# Conducting multi-line string operation with awk instead of for-loop

Tags: awk, string

Assume a multi-line text file (`file1`) that contains filepaths.

```
$ cat file1
./foo/foo
./foo/bar
./foo/baz
```

I would like to save only the filenames to `file2` and prepend each filename with some special characters (e.g., `[#`).

I know that I can do this via a simple for-loop, but I understand this is considered an unfavorable practice.

```
for line in $(cat file1); do
echo "[#" $(basename "$line") >> file2;
done
```

I believe this task can be done cleaner via `awk`, but the below code is only a fragment. How do I perform the above task with `awk`?

```
awk '{print "[#",$0=$(basename $0)}' $file1 > $file2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `/` as the field separator, and print the last field:

```
$ awk -F/ '{print "[#"$NF}' file1
[#foo
[#bar
[#baz
```

Comment: Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e 's|.*/|[#|' file1
```

### Result

```
[#foo
[#bar
[#baz
```